# spring eclipselink problem with IntegrityException

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink

I try to use spring with eclipseLink and I've got an IntegrityException. 
This is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<import resource="data-source.xml" />

<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<!-- Entity manager -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="unit1" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DerbyPlatform" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        </bean>
        <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"> -->
        <!-- <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" 
            /> -->
        <!-- <property name="showSql" value="true" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="generateDdl" value="true" /> -->
        <!-- </bean> -->
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

and exactly exception is:

[EL Config]: 2011-06-09 00:15:24.061--ServerSession(2050312009)--Connection(473155160)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/springhib;create=true
    User: app
    Database: Apache Derby  Version: 10.6.2.1 - (999685)
    Driver: Apache Derby Network Client JDBC Driver  Version: 10.7.1.1 - (1040133)
[EL Severe]: 2011-06-09 00:15:24.127--ServerSession(2050312009)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions:

Exception [EclipseLink-148] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The container policy [CollectionContainerPolicy(class org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectSet)] is not compatible with transparent indirection.
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToManyMapping[comments]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(pl.adaknet.hibspring.domain.ArtEntity --> [DatabaseTable(ARTENTITY)])

but i don't have this problem when I use another Vendor

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this loadtimeweaver implementation:

```
package net.palesz.util;

import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver;

public class JpaAwareLoadTimeWeaver extends SimpleLoadTimeWeaver {
    @Override
    public ClassLoader getInstrumentableClassLoader() {
        ClassLoader instrumentableClassLoader = super.getInstrumentableClassLoader();
        if (instrumentableClassLoader.getClass().getName().endsWith("SimpleInstrumentableClassLoader")) {
            return instrumentableClassLoader.getParent();
        } else {
            return instrumentableClassLoader;
        }
    }
}
```

Spring context.xml config:

```
<bean id="loadTimeWeaver" class="net.palesz.util.JpaAwareLoadTimeWeaver" />
```

Comment: I ran into this same problem with SimpleLoadTimeWeaver and would like to report that the above class does indeed work with EclipseLink.  Thanks Palesz.

Answer (score 0):

An odd error because IndirectSet is valid.  It seems to be a class loader issue, but I have not seen this in Spring before.

It could be related to your usage of loadTimeWeaver, so you could try removing that.

In what environment are you running Spring?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use agent for dynamic weaving 
-javaagent:spring-agent-2.5.6.jar
i had tried eclipseLink agent, but it didn't work.

more info about weaving for JPA on Spring:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch14s06.html

if you would like run your code on tomcat:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch14s06.html#orm-jpa-setup-lcemfb-tomcat

Comment: Please, put some other info in your answer